# Can I check whether an asynchronous function is running?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm building a shell script that calls various functions. When all functions are done I'd like to close the database connection and exit.

If I could somehow get an event every time an asynchronous job starts and ends I could handle it, but is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confused by your question,
You could use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module in this way:

```
var async = require('async');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

async.parallel( [
    //Spawn slow proccesses
    function(cb){ exec('cat *.js bad_file | wc -l', cb ) }, 
    function(cb){ exec('cat *.js bad_file2 | wc -l', cb ) },
    function(cb){ exec('cat *.js bad_file3 | wc -l', cb ) }
], 
function( err ){
    //If there is an error, the callback returns an error will be put in "err"
    if( err != null )
        console.log( err ); 

    //All done, quit!
    require("process").exit();
} );
```

Comment: That could work, but since my functions calls API's, update the database and such I would need a lot of that kind of logic and lots of callbacks. I've so far made my own: https://gist.github.com/1274105

Comment: Could I every 5 second check if a process is active?

Comment: It is still a bit misty on what you are trying to accomplish. I find the "continuation passing style" of NodeJs perfectly fine for knowing when a job finished when having a sequence of calls if used correctly. Could you explain a little more on what you are trying to do?